# How do I export or sync data from TD Ameritrade into Google Finance or another online Finance site?

Tags: google-finance

I'm tired of TD ameritrade's web experience and open to other websites or programs that could pull TD-ameritrade information into an easier to view online interface.

Comment: Have you looked into mint.com?

Comment: mint does pull TD-ameritrade successfully, but it would be nice to have something that's more open format to allow me to export data into a CSV format

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Mint](http://www.mint.com) is one alternative. If you want the raw data in CSV format, you can use "Export" feature under

```
Accounts -> History & Statements -> Transactions Tab -> Select Date Range -> Click Download
```

Comment: Or just on the transaction tab, but yup, it is there.